# Get all values from each key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I just learned that:

```
coloring_dictionary = {}
coloring_dictionary.setdefault(key, [])
coloring_dictionary[key].append(1)
coloring_dictionary[key].append(77)
coloring_dictionary[key].append(3)
```

Would give me a dictionary with one key, that maps to three values(I need this in my project!). Great. Now I want to access and do some operations on each value for each key(in this case only one key, but this applies to several keys too.)

How should I write my for loop in order to get each value, one by one?
This is what I have so far:

```
for key in coloring_dictionary.keys():
    for the_value in coloring_dictionary[key]:
        print(coloring_dictionary[]????)  #here I want to access A value  
        #do some operations on a value
```

Might be a simple answer to this, but I am stuck. Thanks in advance my fellow SO community!

Comment: As an aside, you could also use collections.defaultdict instead of setdefault -> coloring_dictionary = defaultdict(list)

Comment: Are you really asking how to iterate over a list?

Comment: Thnx for the effort you put into your constructive answer Pad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `the_value` should contain the value you`re looking for

```
for key in coloring_dictionary.keys():
    for the_value in coloring_dictionary[key]:
        print(the_value)  # As simple as that
```

**To explain what you`re doing:**

Your dictionary looks something like this:

```
 coloring_dictionary = {
     "key1": [1,2,3,4],
     "key2": [5,6,7,8]
 }
```

In the outer loop, you are iterating over all keys of that dictionary, so the variable `key` contains first 'key1' and then 'key2'.

In the inner loop you are iterating over all values that the dictionary holds at the position of `key`. In the case of 'key1' these are 1,2,3 and 4. These are stored in `the_value`.

Comment: Thank you Maurice. Really simple, but this might help other people out some day!

Answer (score -1):

As an example if you want to multiply the value times two and then reassign/update the dictionary:

```
for key in coloring_dictionary:
    coloring_dictionary[key] = coloring_dictionary[key] * 2
```

In general:

```
def some_function(dictionary_input):
     #Do some stuff to value and save to dictionary_input
     return dictionary_input

for key in coloring_dictionary:
    coloring_dictionary[key] = some_function(coloring_dictionary[key])
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted me half a second after posting, do explain *cough cough other person who posted an aswer*

Comment: Why would I do that?